# Does it improve performance to index a date column?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a table with millions of rows where one of the columns is a TIMESTAMP and against which I frequently select for date ranges.  Would it improve performance any to index that column, or would that not furnish any notable improvement?

EDIT:

So, I've indexed the TIMESTAMP column.  The following query
`select count(*) from interactions where date(interaction_time) between date('2013-10-10') and date(now())`

Takes 3.1 seconds.

There are just over 3 million records in the interactions table.

The above query produces a result of ~976k

Does this seem like a reasonable amount of time to perform this task?

Comment: Performance optimization **is** a rocket science. For the question as it currently asked - it's not possible to tell if it will make it better or worse. Provide more details, including examples of queries you want to optimize and a table schema.

Comment: Sorry, this question is off-topic as it won't help future visitors. Questions require at least your table definition, queries and explain statements. This is something that can really be tested on your own.

Comment: why -1? Seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me (in fact, I've found a very similar question that has +3 votes, it just doesn't address my specific question exactly as I need it answered).

Comment: @GeniaS. Send it my way and I'll make sure it gets downvoted and closed.

Comment: Hypothetical questions such as *"Does this seem like a reasonable amount of time to perform this task?"* are **off-topic**. See the help center.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, there's nothing hypothetical about a reasonable time to perform some well understood task.  I'm not asking how long it should take me to write the code, I'm asking how long should a query take to run, given certain criteria.  You may want to consider that in your zeal to protect the integrity of this site you may be way too rash in your assessments of what is or isn't relevant or useful.

Comment: @GeniaS. There is no "reasonable time" without knowing your hardaware (CPU, RAM, disk IO, etc.) and your data size (100 rows or 100 billion rows?) So that part is really unanswerable as FreshPrince points out. The other part, on whether an index can help, can be (somewaht) answered.

Comment: @ypercube, consider the answers beneath.  They are immediately useful and in no way arbitrary. Obviously CPU/RAM etc al play a huge role, but if you look at what I'm asking, and if you're an expert in this field, it should be immediately obvious if such a task should take .01 seconds (if done right) or 30 minutes (if done very wrong).  My 3 second time may be entirely reasonable or it may be wildly unreasonable... that's all I'm after; am I doing something *really wrong. As it turned out, I am! (woo hoo!)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want improvement on the efficiency of queries, you need 2 things:

- First, index the column.
- Second, and this is more important, make sure the conditions on your queries are **sargable**, i.e. that indexes can be used. In particular, functions should not be used on the columns. In your example, one way to write the condition would be:

  ```
  WHERE interaction_time >= '2013-10-10' 
    AND interaction_time < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ```

Comment: fantastic! that brought it down to 1.5 seconds from 3.1.

Comment: @Genia S.: how many rows (absolute value and in percents) are selected? 1.5 seconds is **A LOT**. Fullscan vs indexed query shouldn't differ by just 2x, it was probably caused by some cache.

Comment: the result was just under a 1/3 of the total rows of the table. I have indexed the interaction_time column and ran your query as printed. Just changed the date to verify that it wasn't cached and it appears that it may have been

Comment: @Genia S.: provide `EXPLAIN` for the query

Comment: @zerkms, explain: 1 SIMPLE interactions range interaction_time_index interaction_time_index 5 NULL 1531970 Using where; Using index

Comment: @GeniaS. and if you remove the `DATE()` ?

Comment: @ypercube, removing date (just leaving 'yyyy-mm-dd') does reduce the time dramatically (down to about 1 second).  Reducing the date range also has MASSIVE impact. If I bring it down to just the last few days, it comes back in 100ms

Comment: Just curious, is the table MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Will `select * from table_name order_by interaction_time  desc limit 10` use the index ?

Comment: @RahulGoyal sure but why don't you try it?

Comment: hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ , if I only need to query the table base on year and month, will I get a better performance if I created a new column with only year and month then index it, instead of create an index of the datetime column directly? Such as that I create a new column whose value is like 201801.

Comment: My queries use >= and <= for the two date fields, = query on a varchar column. How do you think I should add indexes on these columns? Create a combined index or individual non-clustered indexes? Anticipate the rows to have around 20 million rows in all.

Comment: @RedBottleSanitizer do I understand correctly that your WHERE is something like `WHERE a_col = 'sometext' AND b >= '2020-01-01' AND c <= '2022-12-31'` ? In that case a 3-column index probably - `(a,b,c)` or `(a,c,b)` - but depending on your DBMS, there might be some better solution. I suggest you post a new question on the dba site: [dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 6):

The general rule with indexes is they speed retrieval of data with large data sets, but SLOW the insertion and update of records.

If you have millions of rows, and need to select a small subset of them, then an index most likely will improve performance when doing a SELECT. (If you need most or all of them if will make little or no difference.)

Without an index, a table scan (ie read of every record to locate required ones) will occur which can be slow.
With tables with only a few records, a table scan can actually be faster than an index, but this is not your situation.
Another consideration is how many discrete values you have. If you only have a handful of different dates, indexing probably won't help much if at all, however if you have a wide range of dates the index will most likely help.
One caveat, if the index is very big and won't fit in memory, you may not get the performance benefits you might hope for.
Also you need to consider what other fields you are retrieving, joins etc, as they all have an impact.
A good way to check how performance is impacted is to use the EXPLAIN statement to see how mySQL will execute the query.

Answer (score 3):

It would improve performance if:

- there are at least "several" different values
- your query uses a date range that would select less than "most" of the rows

To find out for sure, use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to show what index is being used. Use explain before creating the index and again after - you should see that the new index is being used or not. If its being used, you can be confident performance is better.

You can also simply compare query timings.

Answer (score 2):

For

```
select count(*) from interactions where date(interaction_time) between date('2013-10-10') and date(now())
```

query to be optimized you need to do the following:

1. Use just `interaction_time` instead of `date(interaction_time)`
2. Create an index that covers `interaction_time` column
3. (optional) Use just `'2013-10-10'` not `date('2013-10-10')`

You need #1 because indexes are only used if the columns are used in comparisons as-is, not as arguments in another expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index on date column definitely increases performance.

My table has 11 million rows, and a query to fetch rows which were updated on a particular date took the following time according to conditions:

Without index: ~2.5s

With index: ~5ms

Comment: My queries use >= and <= for the two date fields, = query on a varchar column. How do you think I should add indexes on these columns? Create a combined index or individual non-clustered indexes? Anticipate the rows to have around 20 million rows in all.